# How Do I Fix Steam For Ubuntu?

Tags: steam

I recently downloaded Steam from the website, and when it downloaded and save, I could not open it, yet it would come up saying "updating steam" when I ran it. I read up on it and found that if i type these commands it would work:

```
mv ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1{,.disable}

mv ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6{,.disable}
```

Doing this didn't work, and failed with `No such file or directory`, so I changed it to my steam directory, but it still did not work. I was going to attempt to uninstall steam using terminal, but "Ubuntu doesn't have access to those files." How can I either fix this or uninstall Steam?

Answer (score 1):

Simply do the lines you did again after steams initial update and all will be fine. I even made me a shell sript zo run those commands because it is very likely that you have to rerun it every time when steam updates, az least untill they figure this out.